# BigQuery new data type DATE

Tags: google-bigquery

I see a new data type`DATE` being introduced in the BigQuery Web UI but not documented in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types.
[image: BigQuery UI data type dropdown]
Well `DATE` as such is not new but I have one major question. Unlike `TIMESTAMP` does `DATE` ignore timezone information after being stored.

Quoted text from `TIMESTAMP` documentation:

> You can supply a timezone offset in your date and time strings, but
>   BigQuery doesn't preserve the offset after converting the value to its
>   internal format. If you need to preserve the original timezone data,
>   store the timezone offset in a separate column.

Also whats the expected input for this format. I have tried the known timestamp strings but it does not seem to work.

Comment: You're right that we still need to update our main data types page. Mikhail's link to the standard SQL reference should convey similar information to what we will include there soon though.

Comment: With more products and features, navigating through developer docs gets tricky. Something really needs to be done about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see a new data typeDATE being introduced in the BigQuery Web UI but
>   not documented

Date type was introduced with Standard SQL - see [Date type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types#date-type) for details

> Also whats the expected input for this format

Canonical format

```
'YYYY-[M]M-[D]D'
YYYY: Four-digit year
[M]M: One or two digit month
[D]D: One or two digit day
```

Note: The DATE type represents a logical calendar date, **independent of time zone.**